# CSS: fixed position

Tags: css-position, fixed

I'm new here so I thank you in advance for your help.

I do have a 3 columns page and I want to have the 1st and the 3rd ones fixed (they don't have to scroll with the middle column).

Everything works fine but I positioned these 3 columns in a container div which has a 100% width and a 100% height but also a min width and height.

My problem is that my 3rd column positioned on the right of my page (my footer has the same problem) doesn't block at the min width defined for the container.

If I change the position to absolute to the 3rd column it works but it scrolls with the content.

Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: Show us the code please. Preferably in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to the container `div`